# Prettier: add space between function parenthesis and parameters

Tags: javascript, prettier

I would like to make code like this:

```js
const someFunc = (param1, param2) => {}
```

look like this:

```js
const someFunc = ( param1, param2 ) => {}
```

Where can I find the given setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue regarding this in the `prettier` repo: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1303.

Prettier decided not to support this:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1303#issuecomment-302975431

However, there are some people explaining ways how to achieve it anyway:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1303#issuecomment-318203273